# Solution of the ODE $\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{d^k}{dt^k}x(t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm finding a general formula to solve the ODE:
$$\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{d^k}{dt^k}x(t)=0$$
I suppose the solution to be a combination of $\exp$ and $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, but I'm unable to find a general formula for $x_N(t)$. Thanks

Comment: This is just an ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: ...also initial conditions would be nice...

Comment: No problem.  First figure out how to factor $1-k+k^2-k^3+\dots$ as a polynomial in $k$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: without to specify the initial conditions I expect to have $N$ undeterminated coefficients.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra I understand but it might open it up to some Laplace?

Comment: @EricTowers I am having a moment... why the minuses?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: If the Laplace transform can help to find the solutions we can suppose we have $N$ initial conditions.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy:  Habit.  $\mathrm{e}^{-k t}$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^N \lambda^k = \dfrac{\lambda^{N+1}-1}{\lambda-1}$.  The roots are the $N+1$'th roots of unity, except for $1$.
So the general solution is 
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j \exp(e^{ij/(2 \pi (N+1))} t)$$

Comment: +1 I am profoundly embarrassed that I wrote down $\lambda^n+\cdots+\lambda+1$ in front of me and didn't think geometric series.